# Node unit tests - TypeError: Cannot read property 'order' of undefined

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, proxyquire

I'm getting the following error, `Error: BLANKET-Error parsing instrumented code: TypeError: Cannot read property 'order' of undefined` in my test code indicating the line where `testedModule = proxyquire('../index', {`.

Can anyone see why I am getting this error?

My test file:

```
    pattern: function (filename) {
        return !/node_modules/.test(filename);
    }
});

// in terminal, type the following command to get code coverage: mocha -R html-cov > coverage.html


var chai = require('chai');
var sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");
var sinon = require('sinon');
chai.use(sinonChai);
var proxyquire = require('proxyquire').noCallThru();
var expect = chai.expect;
var mockDir = require('mock-fs');
var extend = require('lodash').extend;

describe("Invoicer", function () {
    describe("Success call", function () {
        var fileReader = require('../fileReader');
        var getObject = require('../getObject');
        var sendEmail = require('../sendEmail');

        var baseEvent = {
            order: "http://orange/order/1234",
            email: '<mario@hevnly.com>'
        };

        var testedModule, fakePath, fakeTemplate, fakeData, fakeMessage, eventObj, fileReaderStub, getObjectStub, sendEmailStub, callbackSpy;

        before(function () {

            eventObj = extend({}, baseEvent);

            fileReaderStub = sinon.stub(fileReader, 'read');

            getObjectStub = sinon.stub(getObject, '_get');

            sendEmailStub = sinon.stub(sendEmail, '_send');

            callbackSpy = sinon.spy();

            testedModule = proxyquire('../index', {
                './fileReader': {
                    'read': fileReaderStub
                },
                './getObject': {
                    '_get': getObjectStub
                },
                './sendEmail': {
                    '_send': sendEmailStub
                }
            });

            fakePath = "path/to/file.html";

            fakeMessage = "Email sent";

            fakeTemplate = "WhatcanIsay";

            fakeData = "Hello World";

            getObjectStub.callsArgWith(1, null, fakeData);

            fileReaderStub.callsArgWith(2, null, fakeTemplate);

            sendEmailStub.callsArgWith(2, null, fakeMessage);

            testedModule.Invoicer(eventObj, {done: function (error, result) {
                console.log("Here!");
                callbackSpy.apply(null, arguments);
            }});
        });

        after(function () {
            fileReader.read.restore();
            getObject._get.restore();
            sendEmail._send.restore();
        });

        it("context.done is called with no error", function () {
            expect(callbackSpy).has.been.called;
        });
    });
});
```

This is `index.js`

```
'use strict';

var async = require('async');

var obj = require("./config.json");

var fileReader = require('./fileReader');
var _readFile = fileReader.read;

var getObject = require('./getObject');
var _getObject = getObject._get;

var sendEmail = require('./sendEmail');
var _sendEmail = sendEmail._send;


exports.Invoicer = function (event, context) {

    console.log("Order: %s", event.order);
    console.log("Email: %s", event.email);
    var urlPath =  event.order; // process.argv[2]; // The url for the order endpoint
    var _recipient = event.email; //process.argv[3]; // The recipient of the email
    var _filePath = obj.filePath;

    async.waterfall([
        function retrieveObject (next) {
            console.log("waterfall getobject");
            _getObject(urlPath, next);
        },
        function _readF (data, next) {
            console.log("waterfall reafile");
            _readFile(data, _filePath, next);
        },
        function sendsEmail (popHtml, next) {
            console.log("waterfall sendemail");
            _sendEmail(popHtml, _recipient, next);
        }
    ], function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Error waterfall");
            return;
            context.done(error);
        } else {
            console.log("Done!");
            return;
            context.done(result);
        }
    });
};

if (!process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT) {
    exports.Invoicer();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this code path ever get executed? If so, it would throw that error as you are not passing any arguments, hence `event.order` would result in `TypeError: undefined`

```
if (!process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT) {
    exports.Invoicer();
}
```